# Swift, iOS: How do I extract data from my firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: database]

This is my firebase database.
I wish to go through my database to grab each ticket's value such as "ignore", "Peter rabbit....", "Incredibles 2....", etc.

Currently I am extracting data like this:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
ref?.child("users").child(uid!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String:String] {
        self.movieNameFromTickets.append(myValue)
    }

})
```

But I feel that it isn't a good way to extract data because if I have another structure like tickets, it might print out the wrong information.

What would be a better way to extract my tickets' values?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Database
    .database()
    .reference()
    .child("Users")
    .child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
    .child("Advertisements")
    .queryOrderedByKey()
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        // get value from dict here .
    })
```